# Blur QPixmap with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im trying to render an image with PyQt5, but it's too small for to see properly, due to high computational power needed.
So I resized it, but now I can see all the pixel clearly what I don't want.
Is there a way to blur this QPixmap, so I no longer see pixel but a smooth image?

Comment: Show us the code how you are resizing it.

Comment: If you are using `QPixmap::scaled()` then you should probably use `transformationMode` parameter and set it to `Qt::SmoothTransformation`.

Comment: @Mikecraft1224 Note that you don't see "all the pixels", you see the [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) caused by the sampling of the pixels (a single pixel showing the contents of what was more than one pixel), and in fast scaling this results in sampling only the closest source pixel that maps to the target. The *anti-aliasing* applied by the `SmoothTransformation` uses a filter that *smooths* those target pixels using bilinear filtering.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite better now with SmoothTransformation.